# matching paint color over different wall coverings

Tags: paint

I removed wallpaper from one wall due to moisture but am leaving it up on the other three walls since the removal damaged the wall and the wallpaper is still adhering well. I am now trying to find paint and I like the color on drywall but not over wallpaper.I used kilz but it did not change the fact the color over wallpaper was so much lighter. How do I get paint to match over both?

Comment: Did you put Kilz on all of the walls, or just the wall where you removed the wallpaper? Different walls may also appear to have different colors due to the way the light hits them, best to look at night where you can control the light.

Answer (score 1):

You need to hit all the walls with Kilz until they are consistent.  The purpose of primer is to make dissimilar underlying surfaces similar so the paint goes on equally.

That is not the job of paint.  You can do it with *many* coats, but why? Primer is cheaper than paint.  Also, the paint chips that you picked your colors from are exemplars of your paint over white, not whatever colors you are covering up.

If you're saying "primer isn't getting the job done", what you're really saying is "I'm not willing to use enough coats of primer to get the job done, and I somehow want that to work out anyway."

Answer (score 0):

The only proper way to get a quality paint job is to remove the wallpaper first.